# Application error(0xc000007b) when runnning Opencv example in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: opencv, visual-studio-2015

I am running canny edge example in Visual Studio 2015 and i got this error.

The application was unable to start correctly (0xc000007b).

And then visual studio show to this error.

Unhandled exception at 0x77A2D5B2 (ntdll.dll) in Canny Edge.exe: 0xC000007B:  %hs is either not designed to run on Windows or it contains an error. Try installing the program again using the original installation media or contact your system administrator or the software vendor for support. Error status 0x.

I quite sure this coding is working as i ran this coding before in Visual Studio 2013. Here is my coding.

```
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"

#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

void help()
{
    cout << "\nThis program demonstrates line finding with the Hough transform.\n"
        "Usage:\n"
        "./houghlines <image_name>, Default is pic1.jpg\n" << endl;
}

bool less_by_y(const cv::Point& lhs, const cv::Point& rhs)
{
    return lhs.y < rhs.y;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    const char* filename = argc >= 2 ? argv[1] : "pic1.jpg";

    vector<vector<Point> > contours;
    vector<Vec4i> hierarchy;
    Rect roi;

    Mat src = imread("test_4_1.png");
    if (src.empty())
    {
        help();
        cout << "can not open " << filename << endl;
        return -1;
    }

    Mat dst, cdst;
    Canny(src, dst, 50, 200, 3);
    cvtColor(dst, cdst, CV_GRAY2BGR);
    findContours(dst, contours, hierarchy, CV_RETR_TREE, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, Point(0, 0));

    //vector<Vec2f> lines;
    //HoughLines(dst, lines, 1, CV_PI / 180, 50, 0, 0);

    //for (size_t i = 0; i < lines.size(); i++)
    //{
    //  float rho = lines[i][0], theta = lines[i][1];
    //  Point pt1, pt2;
    //  double a = cos(theta), b = sin(theta);
    //  double x0 = a*rho, y0 = b*rho;
    //  pt1.x = cvRound(x0 + 1000 * (-b));
    //  pt1.y = cvRound(y0 + 1000 * (a));
    //  pt2.x = cvRound(x0 - 1000 * (-b));
    //  pt2.y = cvRound(y0 - 1000 * (a));
    //  line(cdst, pt1, pt2, Scalar(0, 0, 255), 1, CV_AA);
    //  cout << pt1 << "    " << pt2 << endl;
    //}

    vector<Vec4i> lines;
    HoughLinesP(dst, lines, 1, CV_PI / 180, 30, 50, 10);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < lines.size(); i++)
    {
        Vec4i l = lines[i];
        line(cdst, Point(l[0], l[1]), Point(l[2], l[3]), Scalar(0, 0, 255), 1, CV_AA);
        cout << l << endl;
    }

    cout << endl << lines.size() << endl;
    cout << arcLength(contours[0], true) << endl;
    cout << dst.size() << endl << endl;

    for (int a = 0; a < contours[0].size(); a++){
        cout << contours[0][a] << " ";
    }

    vector<Point> test = contours[0];
    auto mmx = std::minmax_element(test.begin(), test.end(), less_by_y);
    cout << endl << *mmx.first._Ptr << endl << *mmx.second._Ptr;

    vector<Point> test2 = contours[1];
    auto mmx_1 = std::minmax_element(test2.begin(), test2.end(), less_by_y);
    cout << endl << *mmx_1.first._Ptr << endl << *mmx_1.second._Ptr;

    imshow("source", src);
    imshow("detected lines", cdst);

    /* ROI by creating mask for the parallelogram */
    Mat mask = cvCreateMat(dst.size().height, dst.size().width, CV_8UC1);
    // Create black image with the same size as the original
    for (int i = 0; i < mask.cols; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < mask.rows; j++)
            mask.at<uchar>(Point(i, j)) = 0;

    cout <<endl<<endl<< *mmx.first._Ptr << *mmx.second._Ptr << *mmx_1.first._Ptr << *mmx_1.second._Ptr << endl;

    // Create Polygon from vertices
    vector<Point> ROI_Vertices = { *mmx.first._Ptr, *mmx.second._Ptr, *mmx_1.first._Ptr, *mmx_1.second._Ptr};

    vector<Point> ROI_Poly;
    approxPolyDP(ROI_Vertices, ROI_Poly, 1.0, false);

    // Fill polygon white
    fillConvexPoly(mask, &ROI_Poly[0], ROI_Poly.size(), 255, 8, 0);
    cout << ROI_Poly.size() << endl;

    // Create new image for result storage
    Mat imageDest = cvCreateMat(dst.size().height, dst.size().width, CV_8UC3);

    // Cut out ROI and store it in imageDest
    src.copyTo(imageDest, mask);

    imshow("mask", mask);
    imshow("image", imageDest);

    waitKey();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What OpenCV Libs are you linking to? Are you linking to vs12? Because you need to upgrade your linker to vs13 for MSVS 2015

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually my comment is the answer, with some additions

> What OpenCV Libs are you linking to? Are you linking to vs12? Because
>   you need to upgrade your linker to vs13 for MSVS 2015

OpenCV Doesn't come with Visual Studio 15 pre-builds, so you need to build OpenCV yourself for VS2015

[This person](http://dogfeatherdesign.com/opencv-3-0-microsoft-visual-studio-2015-cmake-and-c/) seems to have had a similar problem and talks you through how to compile for VS2015

Comment: Thanks you very much!